# Directive in directive Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to AngularJS and I am trying to create directive which contains another directive inside.

Here how first directive look like

(

```
function () {
    app.directive("cmEventBar", function () {

        var controller = function () {
            var vm = this;
            vm.events = [
                {name: "Truckdriver1", eventId: 1 },
                {name: "Truckdriver2", eventId: 1 },
                {name: "Truckdriver3", eventId: 1 }
            ];
        }

        return {
            templateUrl: "app/shared/eventsBar/eventBar.html",
            restrict: "E",
            controller: controller,
            priority: 1000,
            terminal: true,
            controllerAs: "vm",
            scope: {}
        };
    });
})();
```

Inside html of this directive I am using ng-repeat to show all events. Insinde ng-repeat I have another directive:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in vm.events">
            <cm-single-event name="{{item.name}}" eventId="{{item.eventId}}"></cm-single-event>
        </div>
```

Here how second directive look like:

```
(function () {
    app.directive("cmSingleEvent", function () {

        var controller = function () {
            var vm = this;
            vm.info = switchEvent(eventId);
         }

        return {
            template: "<li class={{vm.info.itemClass}}> {{vm.name}} {{vm.info.messege}} </li>",
            restrict: "E",
            controller: controller,
            controllerAs: "vm",
            scope: {
                name: "=",
                eventId: "="
            }
        };
    });
})();
```

The output is a little weird because event has 3 elements and in output I see only one element + there are no vm.info from directive inside.

**Output**

> {{vm.name}} {{vm.info.messege}}

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is `switchEvent`?

Comment: its simple javascript function which return me info about event by id

Comment: eventId should be written event-id on the HTML side. Also use bindToController: true to get access to name and eventId on vm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using `=` for `name` & `eventId`, you should not use `{{}}` while assigning there value in attribute & `cmSingleEvent` directive should have `bindToController: true` to retrieve value from `isolated scope` to controller `this`(context)

```
<cm-single-event name="item.name" event-id="item.eventId"></cm-single-event>
```

Comment: @miechooy Pleased to know that, Thanks :-)